# Recover my corrupted latex folder

Tags: texmaker

My pc is crushed so I opened my backup Disque to found that all my files in my latex folder are corrupted,  I worked a lot on my tex file so I want a solution to recover it, please

when I open the file on TexMaker it shows

> it seems that this file cannot be correctly decoded with the default
> encoding setting utf8

knowing that the file was created on ubuntu and opened on windows
files that I have .bbl, .aux, .dvi

whatever the encoding that I put it shows special characters

Comment: Have you tried to open the file(s) with a plain text editor such as VIM? Now, it sounds like you could have had a virus and if that's the case, your files are gone. But opening in plain text may reveal the code if the issue is something else.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, unfortunately, yes I tried and all that I got is a series of letter ß

Comment: disk recovery is not really on topic here, the data may be recoverable or you may need to restore the file from backup, but it is not related to tex, sorry.